# Difference between refreshing Materialized View in DB Vs Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a project that makes forecast with SQL (postgresql) process and python process. The preparation of information before the python procees begins needs that a series of Materialized Views. 
Right now i'm refreshings those views with sqlAlchemy and there is a difference, because when python refresh it the column date ( that comes from the query that makes a date_trunc('month',date)) is not the month of the date of the previous table but the last day of the previous month of the date of the original table.

As an example:
Table 1 has date from 2017-12-02 to 2018-02-04 
the result of the date_trunc should be:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000
2017-12-01 00:00:00.000000
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000000
```

But the result is:

```
mes
2017-11-30 21:00:00.000000
2017-12-31 21:00:00.000000
2018-01-31 21:00:00.000000
```

Is there anything to be done about this?

Comment: yes- unify clients `TimeZone`. I guess python tz is GMT+3 and sql querying client has UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your different clients have different time zones. to demonstrate it I'll do this:

```
t=# create table so6(t timestamp,tz timestamptz);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so6 select date_trunc('month',now()),date_trunc('month',now());
INSERT 0 1
t=# set timezone to 'GMT-3';
SET
t=# insert into so6 select date_trunc('month',now()),date_trunc('month',now());
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from so6;
          t          |           tz
---------------------+------------------------
 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 03:00:00+03
 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00+03

(2 rows)
```

As you can see depending on your client TimeZone setting results differ.

Now if you select result back with first client time zone, you get:

```
t=# set timezone to 'utc';
SET
t=# select * from so6;
          t          |           tz
---------------------+------------------------
 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00+00
 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-31 21:00:00+00
(2 rows)
```

which looks like your case

Comment: It was exactly my problem, i solved the issue by setting the TIME ZONE when the connection to de server is made by python.